# How to refresh my Partial View after Ajax Post in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So basically I'm trying to show some Profile Data in my MVC Application.
Right now, everytime I click on a date on my Telerik Kendo Calendar, I can refresh the whole page and update the data I want.

However, instead of refreshing the whole I just want to refresh the partial views that shows only the data that updates after selecting the date.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!--CODE-->
  @Html.Partial("_WorkingTimeData")
<!--CODE-->
```

**_WorkingTimeData.cshtml**

```
 var workedTime = ViewData["WorkedTimeToday"];
 var hoursPerDay = ViewData["HoursPerDayContract"];

    <p>You worked @workedTime hours</p>
    <p>Hours Per Day (Contract) @hoursPerDay Hours</p>
```

Yes, right now I'm ViewDatas and it works.

**This is the ajax code in Index.cshtml**

```
  $.ajax({ url: '/Profile/Index',
                            dataType: "json", 
                            type: "POST", 
                            data: JSON.stringify(10), 
                            success: function(returl){ 
                                alert('It worked'); 
                                location.href=returl.Url;
                            }, 
                            error: function(jqXHR,responseText,textStatus){ alert(jqXHR.responseText) } });
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string number){

        //THINGS TO DO
        var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Profile");
        return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
    }
```

Well I'm very new to this, and I've been doing my research. However I still have some questions:
- Do I need to create a post method for _WorkingTimeData instead of Index like I have?
- Do I need to create a ViewModel for the Partial View?

Thanks

EDIT NUMBER 2 FOR VISHAL:

This didn't work at all, not even an alert, because, strangely, it doesn't recognise the calendar...

```
$("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                        change : function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Profile/WorkingTimeData",
                                type: "get"
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                $("#profile-timeline").html(data);
                            });
                        }});
```

It says $("#calendar").kendoCalendar is not a function (Telerik says that it's this way)

As for this, it reached the controller but didn't update anything:

```
 function change() {
                        alert("Escolheste outro dia");
                        var calendar = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");
                        var current = calendar.current();
                        alert(current);
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/Profile/WorkingTimeData",
                                        type: "get"
                                    }).done(function(data) {
                                        $("#profile-timeline").html(data);
                                    });
                                }
```

I think it's because of the profile-timeline... It's a div in my view

Comment: Do you just want to refresh the kendo control or the whole view?

Comment: None of these. Just the partial view that shows the worked time and the contract hours.

Comment: @Cajux94: remove $(document).ready. and then try. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Do I need to create a post method for `_WorkingTimeData`?

Yes, you need to create. But, Get would be fine too.

Do I need to create a `ViewModel` for the Partial View?
Not needed. If required you can create.

But, by looking at your partial view you are just using `ViewData[""]`. So, you need not to create any `ViewModel`.

Just create a method in `Controller` returning `_WorkingTimeData` `PartialView`.
And call that method by `JQuery ajax` on your `DatePicker` change event and replace the contents of the `Div`.

For example.
`Controller`

```
public PartialViewResult WorkingTimeData()
{
    ViewData["WorkedTimeToday"]="NEW VALUE";
    ViewData["HoursPerDayContract"] = "NEW VALUE";
    return this.PartialView("_WorkingTimeData");
}
```

JavaScript

```
       $("DATEPICKERELEMENT").change(function() {
           $.ajax({
               url: "/CONTROLLER/WorkingTimeData",
               type: "get"
           }).done(function(data) {
               alert(data);
               $("#divisionIdContainingPartialView").html(data);
           }).fail(function() {
               alert('error');
           });
       });
```

Comment: Look at my edit above, because I can't comment here the code x)

Comment: @Cajux94: Please post the controller WorkingTimeData method code. and what did you get the response from the ajax call. and make sure the partialview is in profile-timeline div.

Comment: The controller method is like the one you gave me. The partialview is in the profile-timeline div, more than confirmed. As for the return, it returns what it's supposed to, I guess...

Comment: @Cajux94: check my edit. and see if ajax call is throwing any error or it succeeds.

Comment: It's working... I was doing a mistake when I input the code... Forgot that it was html(data) and I just had html... Hahaha, sometimes programmers get the most stupid errors and take longer to solve them... Thanks for the help and patience x)

Comment: @Cajux94: You can mark this as answer if it is working fine. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post that details why you need to break the logic of thinking about partial views client-side. If you're interested you can find it [here](http://cpratt.co/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-partial-view-client-side/).

The TL;DR version is simply, all you have client-side is HTML. There's no knowledge about what was or was not rendered to the response via a partial view. As a result, the real question is "How do I change a portion of my HTML page based on an AJAX response?". In the simplest form, you simply select some element on the page and then alter its inner HTML. You can do that with some custom HTML created client-side or you can actually pass back an HTML document as your AJAX response and then insert that.